# Is there a website for academic physics jobs in the US like mathjobs.org?

Tags: application, job-search, postdocs, physics

I am in math, and we usually apply to most academic jobs (in the US) through a generic application at mathjobs.org. Is there an equivalent in physics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In particle/nuclear physics there is http://inspirehep.net/collection/Jobs
More generally, many (but definitely not all) physics jobs are announced on http://academicjobsonline.org.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any physics-wide collection of jobs. The closest thing I know of is the HEP (particle physics) rumor mills, where jobs are linked and results are posted.

Theory:
http://particle.physics.ucdavis.edu/rumor/doku.php?id=current

Experiment:
https://sites.google.com/site/hepexrumor/